# About Approval Process Urgent

Tags: approval-process, standard-objects

1) I want to know about ProcessInstance , ProcessInstanceSteps and ProcessInstanceWorkItem   what is relation among them and when a record is sent for approval then I think some records are created but by don't records are created for which sobject.

2) Also want to know what is ActorId and OrignalActorId.

3) how can I find, how many records have approved by a user.

Advance thank

Comment: What do you need to know that's not in the documentation? What parts specifically do you not understand?

Comment: I want to know that when a user sumitted a record for approval and a processInstace is created and then how many steps are created and what is role of workitem when it will be creted,I also want to know when user approved or reject a reocord then a process instace will be created or step are created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `ProccessInstance` is parent of `ProcessInstanceSteps` and `ProcessInstanceWorkItem`. `ProcessInstanceSteps`  stores the steps followed by approvers (one or more) e.g; accept, reject  or reassign. `Comments`, `ActorId` and `OriginalActorId` etc., all these saved in ProcessInstanceSteps. It is created for each new step taken by approver.  And information like OriginalactorId, (parent) processInstanceId etc are saved in ProcessInstanceWorkItem. It mostly used for pending approvals.

2) `OriginalactorId` is the first person who is authorized to take action on record and `actorId` is the person who is currently assigned (In several steps `actorId` changes and when reassign `OriginalActorId` changes). `ActorId` and `OriginalActorId` also available in `ProcessInstanceWorkItem`.

3) By query from ProccessInstance to child ProcessInstanceSteps  you can get who approved/rejected the record. `ProccessInstance` can be used to get status of record and on which `sObject`.

For more details about fields, start reading from [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your implemented your approval process but here is what use :

```
List<ProcessInstance> processInstances = [select Id, Status, TargetObjectId,
                                                //that's the Approval History in your page layout
                                                (select ActorId, Comments, ProcessInstanceId, OriginalActorId, StepStatus from Steps order by CreatedDate asc)
                                        from ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId = 'your_record_id'];

System.debug('+---------$ Your record['+processInstances[0].Steps[0].TargetObjectId+'] is submitted');
System.debug('+---------$ Submitter : '+processInstances[0].Steps[0].OriginalActorId);
System.debug('+---------$ Approver : '+processInstances[0].Steps[0].ActorId);
```

I didn't really check if the syntax is correct but should be something like that.

Comment: Hi,
System.debug('+---------$ Submitter : '+processInstances[0].Steps[0].OriginalActorId);
System.debug('+---------$ Approver : '+processInstances[0].Steps[0].ActorId); both give me same user

Comment: As I said, depend on how you implemented your approval process. If this user is a System Admin, he might be the submitter and the approver too. Try to debug the whole list of Steps.System.debug('+---------$ Steps : '+processInstances[0].Steps);

Comment: Late edit, but it should be `processInstances[0].TargetObjectId` in the debug statement